# Why cant a RandomAccessFile be casted to Inputstream?

Tags: java, java-io

I get compilation error when I do this cast:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(...)
InputStream is = (InputStream)raf;
```

`RandomAccessFile` is supposed to subclass `InputStream` although not directly.

From docs:

`RandomAccessFile` implements `DataInput` which inturn `DataInputstream` & `InputStream`

Why is this invalid?

Also appreciate your input on what would be the right way to use the `RandomAccessFile` as `InputStream`?

I am thinking of wrapper approach.

Comment: The point of a `RandomAccessFile` is that it isn't a stream (it's not sequential). Why would you want to change that? Just make a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: And what do you mean by your "file cache is not disturbed with RAF..."? What is the ultimate goal of this code? You will need to tell the details if you want help solving a problem. Consider checking out this link [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) which contains great tips on how to make forum questions more easily answered.

Comment: @Jeffrey well that is ignorant... There are numerous cases. For instance, if you use `IOUtils.copyLarge` from apache commons that uses `InputStream`, so you seek your `RandomAccessFile` and then create wrapper `InputStream`, but again there is no reason why couldn't `RandomAccessFile` extend `InputStream`...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) extends `Object`, and *does not* extend `InputStream`.

If you want get an `InputStream` from a `RandomAccessFile` I think implementing a wrapper class is your simplest bet.  Luckily the only abstract method of `InputStream` is `read()`.

> RandomAccessFile implements DataInput which inturn DataInputstream & InputStream

`DataInputStream` is a subclass of `InputStream`, which also happens to implement `DataInput`.  The inheritance and interface implementation tree looks like this:

```
           InputStream      DataInput
               \              /   \
                \            /     \
                 \          /       \
                DataInputStream   RandomAccessFile
```

You could use a `DataInputStream` anywhere where you could use an `InputStream` or a `DataInput`.  You could use a `RandomAccessFile` anywhere where you could use a `DataInput`.

But you can't go up and then down in the inheritance hierarchy like this using casts.  In particular, casting a class to a subclass (or an interface to an implementation) will raise a `ClassCastException` unless the object happens to be an instance of the child class.

Even though two classes happen to extend `Object` that doesn't mean they are interchangeable.

Comment: sverre, thanks for answering my dumb question.  I didnt read the hierarchy correctly.

Comment: This is easily achievable using the Channels utility class... // STEP 1:  Create random access file read-only
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("/text.txt", "r");

// STEP 2:  Use Channels to convert to InputStream
InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(raf.getChannel());  (answered separately)

Answer (score 55):

This is easily achievable using the Channels utility class...

```
// STEP 1:  Create random access file read-only
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("/text.txt", "r");

// STEP 2:  Use Channels to convert to InputStream
InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(raf.getChannel());
```

Comment: @dpg I feel like it will close the stream after read completes, which is not the case if you read from the file DataInput interface.

Comment: Does that `InputStream` have any kind of buffering, and if so, is that buffer invalidated/refreshed after a position change in the `RandomAccessFile`?

Answer (score 6):

To build on @robert-christian’s answer, the main reason to use `RandomAccessFile` to begin with is to `seek` to some position, rather than `skip`ping bytes from a `FileInputStream`. But then why bother with pre-NIO APIs at all?

```
try (FileChannel ch = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(…), StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
    InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(ch.position(…));
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> RandomAccessFile is supposed to extends InputStream although not
>   directly.

No it isn't. See the Javadoc.

> From docs:
>
> `RandomAccessFile` implements `DataInput` which in turn `DataInputstream` & `InputStream.`

That's not 'from the docs' at all. You made it up. What you've written doesn't even make sense. `DataInput` is an interface. `DataInputStream` and `InputStream` are classes. Interfaces don't implement, or extend, classes.

What the Javadoc actuallys says is that `RandomAccessFile` extends `java.lang.Object` and implements `Closeable, DataInput, DataOutput`.