# Concurrent access to property files

Tags: java, concurrency

I have some corruption problems with property files. What I suspect is that concurrent reading/writing is the problem. So I want to put some file locks.
First I have looked at this: [How can I lock a file using java (if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible)
So I can put locks on write, but not on read, which does not solve my problem.
Then I have looked at this: [Java: how to handle two process trying to modify the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332406/java-how-to-handle-two-process-trying-to-modify-the-same-file)
So if I use RandomAccessFile, I can put lock on read AND write, which seems correct. So my remaining problem is simple: load a Property with RandomAccessFile. But I see no simple way to have a Reader or an InputStream from a RandomAccessFile. Is there one?
Thanks,
Guillaume

Edit: As there is some ambiguity, I have to add that the concurrency is due to multiple processes accessing the file, not multithreading

Comment: Check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287664/why-cant-a-randomaccessfile-be-casted-to-inputstream)

Comment: The lock for write does solve your problem.  It will exclude all other writers but also all other readers (it is called a write lock, but more accurately is an *exclusive* lock).

Comment: @john16384, how does that work? Does the OS prevent other processes from opening the file? Is that guaranteed by Java?

Comment: If the only program accessing this property file is your program, you don’t need file locks;  you can just use synchronization, locks, or one of the many classes in the java.util.concurrent package.

Comment: If you use NIO FileLock, then yes, the OS guarantees it.  Read its docs under the heading "Platform dependencies`.