# How can I use an InputStream for parts of a RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java, inputstream, randomaccessfile

I'm new to Java, and I wrote a parser that works on `RandomAccessFile` (the file format requires random positioning). For JUnit testing I feed different sample input files into the parser.

Now I thought I could write easier JUnit tests after having changed the parser to read from an `InputStream` instead (that would be created by a JUnit test).

But to be able to perform the non-testing use case, I'd have to create (or update) an `InputStream` to read where the `RandomAccessFile` currently points to. *Is that possible?* Of course the solution should be both, efficient and elegant.

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you showed some code.

Comment: @Andy Turner: The code to open a `RandomAcessFile`, the code to read from such a file, or the (not-yet-existing) code to read from an `InputStream`? Or what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287664/why-cant-a-randomaccessfile-be-casted-to-inputstream I get the idea that a `SeekableByteChannel` with `Channels.newInputStream()` sounds like a possible solution, but unbuffered.

Comment: Reading the description of `InputStream` (`BufferedInputStream`) I wonder whether it would be easiest to implement a new class delegating to `RandomAccessFile`, adding `setPosition()` (and invalidating the buffer on position canges in case of `BufferedInputStream`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nobody had a more clever idea, here is what I did. Unfortunately the very restricted nature of constructors and the use of `super()` and the lack of multiple inheritance in Java makes the implementation harder and uglier than necessary. Also the lack of a protected `invalidate()` for the buffer of `BufferedInputStream` caused me to guess how to do it (a test showed that it works):

```
package de.whatever.uw.utils;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

/**
 * @author U. Windl
 */
public class RandomAccessFileInputStream extends BufferedInputStream {

    private RandomAccessFile file;  // file to use

   /**
     * Constructor
     * @param fileName File to open for reading
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public RandomAccessFileInputStream(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(System.in);   // dummy to work around Java's inflexibility
        assert fileName != null;
        file = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
        FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
        in = new BufferedInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(channel));
        assert file != null;
    }

    /**
     * Forbidden Constructor
     * @param in Input stream
     */
    private RandomAccessFileInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    /**
     * Forbidden Constructor
     * @param in
     * @param size
     */
    private RandomAccessFileInputStream(InputStream in, int size) {
        super(in, size);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.io.BufferedInputStream#close()
     */
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();
        file.close();
    }

    /**
     * @return Current offset in stream
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public long getFilePointer() throws IOException {
        return file.getFilePointer();
    }

    /**
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     * @see java.io.RandomAccessFile#length()
     */
    public long length() throws IOException {
        return file.length();
    }

    /**
     * @param pos New stream position
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void seek(long pos) throws IOException {
        file.seek(pos);
        pos = count = 0;    // invalidate stream buffer
    }

    // other methods are inherited without change (and I really use a very few of them actually)
}
```

(I had created a special test file of about 8kB size to test positioning and buffering: After a position change the correct data is read (invalidating the buffer seems to work), and more than the requested data size is read (i.e. buffering also works).)

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed today!